# JavaScript in WordPress Customizer

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

Customizer Codes:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting (
    'script-code',
    array (
        'default' => esc_html__( 'Script Code', 'x' ),
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post'
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_control (
    new WP_Customize_Control (
        $wp_customize,
        'script-code',
        array (
            'label' => esc_html__( 'Script Code', 'x' ),
            'section' => 'script',
            'settings' => 'script-code',
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'priority' => 1
        )
    )
);
```

Photo from Customizer:

[image]

from codes for output:

```
<?php echo wp_kses_post(get_theme_mod('script-code')); ?>
```

from output, return the empty:

```
<main class="script-code">
</main>
```

How can I use script tag in Customizer textarea setting field ?

Thanks so much.

Comment: please explain your question a bit more..

Comment: I can not get the <script>js codes</script> output of the textarea field on the wordpress customizer page.

Comment: need to see snapshot where actually you are putting your code

Comment: Of course, one moment.

Comment: @ArsalanMithani I added photo links.

Comment: at its current form, this is an unreadable question. Please edit it, and add relevant code as **text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using [wp_kses_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/) to sanitize the output data, try without it:

```
<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'script-code'); ?>
```

also remove it from here:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting (
    'script-code',
    array (
        'default' => esc_html__( 'Script Code', 'x' ),
        'sanitize_callback' => '' // remove wp_kses_post
    )
);
```

also make sure you are using the right name of your theme mod you can check that in two ways:

1.- do a `var_dump(get_theme_mods());` check there how is named.

2.- Inspect the `HTML` code of your control in the customizer

[image]

the `id` without the prefix `customize-control-` is the name of your theme mod.

Comment: Still the same issue continues.

Comment: can you `var_dump(get_theme_mod( 'script-code'));` and add that to your question, also the code that you are using to add this control and setting to the customizer are you using any `sanitize_callback`?

Comment: var_dump() output: bool(false)

Comment: that means that theme-mod doesnt exists, can you `var_dump(get_theme_mods());` and check the name of your theme mod i dont think its `'script-code'`

Comment: Every time the value is return empty.

Comment: can you add the array output to your question please, the code for adding the control would be helpful too

Comment: var_dump(get_theme_mods()); output : ["script-code"]=>string(5) "asd"

Comment: how are you adding the textarea?

Comment: please dont put a photo, copy paste the code.

Comment: Okey, I will add it as code.

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: David, my bro you are legend, thank you very very much for everything :)